# Smash products of pointed groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, groupoids

The category of pointed sets $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ has a symmetric closed monoidal category structure $(\wedge,S^0)$, which, analogously to the symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category of pointed spaces, is (I think) the unique symmetric closed monoidal structure on $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ having $S^0=\{0,1\}$ as its unit and whose tensor product $\wedge$ preserves colimits in each variable separately.

Going one level up in the categorical ladder, we have groupoids. This time, pointed can mean four things:

- "Strictly pointed", giving the category $\mathsf{Grpd}_{*}$;
- "Lax pointed", giving the full subcategory $\mathsf{Grpd}^{\mathsf{lax}}_{*}$ of the category $\mathsf{Cats}^{\mathsf{lax}}_*$ of [Kerodon, Tag 01R7](https://kerodon.net/tag/01R7);
- "Oplax pointed" and "strongly pointed", giving categories $\mathsf{Grpd}^{\mathsf{oplax}}_{*}$ and $\mathsf{Grpd}^{\mathsf{strong}}_{*}$, which are defined analogously.

I think that each of these will admit monoidal ($2$-)category structures. For instance, the case of $\mathsf{Grpd}_{*}$ is a special case of [Riehl, *Categorical Homotopy Theory*, Construction 3.3.14](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/cathtpy.pdf#thm.3.3.14), and I think it satisfies the following universal property (like $\mathsf{Sets}_*)$:

> $(\mathsf{Grpd}_{*},\wedge,S^0)$ is the unique symmetric closed monoidal category having $S^{0}=\mathsf{pt}\coprod\mathsf{pt}$ as its unit and whose tensor product $\wedge$ preserves *$2$-colimits* in each variable separately, where the smash product $\wedge$ of two pointed groupoids is defined by
> $$\mathcal{C}\wedge\mathcal{D}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathsf{pt}\coprod_{\mathcal{C}\coprod\mathcal{D}}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}).$$

Regarding the case of $\mathsf{Grpd}^{\mathsf{strong}}_*$:

- Is it known whether it indeed admits such a symmetric closed monoidal ($2$-)category structure?
- If so, does it satisfy a similar universal property? (Perhaps the same as the one above, but with pseudo(bi)colimits replacing $2$-colimits?)

Comment: Since all morphisms in a groupoid are invertible, there's no difference between "lax pointed", "oplax pointed" and "strongly pointed" (these categories have same classes of objects, and canonically isomorphic sets of 1-morphisms between any two objects). Also, at the level of 2-categories there is no difference between "pointed" and  "lax pointed" (the forgetful 2-functor from "lax pointed" to "pointed" is an equivalence of 2-categories)